# How to load test web services in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-services, load-testing

How can i load test web services in visual studio?

Comment: Why must you use Visual Studio? Why not use a tool designed for load testing?

Comment: Which edition of Visual Studio are you using? Ultimate? Professional? Also, which version? 2010? 2008?

Comment: i am having visual studio ultimate 2010

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't involve Visual Studio. However, [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231282) are some free tools from Microsoft for stress testing web applications.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options with VS Ultimate 2010:

- **web tests**:  if the web service calls are simple enough to make (e.g. a url with query string parameters) and the response is simple enough to parse, you can create web tests (now called 'web performance tests') that exercise the web services.
- **unit tests**:  if the web service calls and responses are more complex, you should try this option.  Visual Studio can auto-generate the necessary classes to interface with the web services, given a WSDL file.  In your test project, right-click on the project node, choose Add Service Reference, specify the url of the WSDL file, and it will create the necessary code for you.  Then you can write unit tests using the generated API.

Also see [How to create a web service load test using Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759318/how-to-create-a-web-service-load-test-using-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Web & Load Testing Framework is powerful and extensible.
For testing Web/WCF/API Services, you can use a Load Test.
This test will include a mix of unit test or generated tests from [wcf load test](http://wcfloadtest.codeplex.com/).

But there are also many others tools available :

- [WCFStorm](http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/home.aspx)
- [loadUI](http://www.loadui.org/)
- [So-Aware Test Workbench](http://www.tellagostudios.com/products/so-aware-test-workbench%E2%84%A2)